# Get y coordinates given x and z for a plane in 3D

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I've generated a 3D circular plane that has been rotated along the x-axis by 45 degrees:

[image]

I want to determine the y-coordinate of the plane, given the x and z coordinates, but I can't figure out how to do that.  How do I interpolate the plane such that I can get the y-coordinate if I feed it an x- and z-coordinate?

Here is my code:

```
def coord_rotation(theta):
    # Convert to radians
    theta_1_rad = theta[0] * np.pi/180.0
    theta_2_rad = theta[1] * np.pi/180.0
    theta_3_rad = theta[2] * np.pi/180.0
    # The bicone and dust angles correspond to Euler angles which are 
    # (e1,e2,e3) -> (rotation about z, rotation about x, rotation about z again)
    theta_1,theta_2,theta_3 = theta_1_rad,theta_2_rad,theta_3_rad
    R_x = np.array([[1,         0,                  0                   ],
                    [0,         np.cos(theta_1),   np.sin(theta_1)   ],
                    [0,         -np.sin(theta_1),  np.cos(theta_1)    ]
                    ])
    R_y = np.array([[np.cos(theta_2),    0,        -np.sin(theta_2)    ],
                    [0,                   1,        0                    ],
                    [np.sin(theta_2),    0,         np.cos(theta_2)    ]
                    ])
    R_z = np.array([[np.cos(theta_3),       np.sin(theta_3),        0],
                    [-np.sin(theta_3),      np.cos(theta_3),       0],
                    [0,                      0,                      1]
                    ])             
    R = np.dot(R_z, np.dot( R_y, R_x ))
    return R

theta_D1_deg  = -45.0)
theta_D3_deg  = 0.0  
D = 2
sampling = 25
########################################################################################
phi       = 2*np.pi # rotation 
phi    = np.linspace(0,phi,sampling)
r      = np.linspace(-D,D,sampling)

ri,pi = np.ix_(r,phi) # get open grids            
X = ri*np.cos(pi)
Y = ri*np.sin(pi)
Z = np.zeros(np.shape(X))
# Rotate the dust plane in 3d
t = np.transpose(np.array([X,Y,Z]), (1,2,0))
R = coord_rotation((theta_D1_deg,0,theta_D3_deg))
xd,yd,zd = np.transpose(np.dot(t, R), (2,0,1))

# Make uniform grid
points = (xd.ravel(),yd.ravel())
values = zd.ravel()
xdgrid,ydgrid = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-2,2,1000),np.linspace(-2,2,1000))
zdgrid = griddata(points, values, (xdgrid, ydgrid), method='linear')

# Plot
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, projection='3d')
ax1.view_init(elev=15, azim=35)
ax1.plot_wireframe(xdgrid,ydgrid,zdgrid,alpha=0.25,color='xkcd:orange',zorder=3)

fontsize = 12
# x-axis
ax1.set_xlim(-2,2)
ax1.set_xlabel(r'$x$',fontsize=fontsize)
xAxisLine = ((np.min(xd), np.max(xd)), (0, 0), (0,0))
ax1.plot(xAxisLine[0], xAxisLine[1], xAxisLine[2], color='black',zorder=1,alpha=0.5)
# y-axis
ax1.set_ylim(-2,2)
ax1.set_ylabel(r'$y$',fontsize=fontsize)
yAxisLine = ((0, 0), (np.min(yd), np.max(yd)), (0,0))
ax1.plot(yAxisLine[0], yAxisLine[1], yAxisLine[2], color='black',zorder=1,alpha=0.5)
# z-axis
ax1.set_zlim(-2,2)
ax1.set_zlabel(r'$z$',fontsize=fontsize)
zAxisLine = ((0, 0), (0,0), (np.min(xd), np.max(xd)))
ax1.plot(zAxisLine[0], zAxisLine[1], zAxisLine[2], color='black',zorder=1,alpha=0.5)
plt.tight_layout()
```

Comment: Do you mean disk or plane? If you want to see if a given point on the (x,z) plane can be mapped to the disk, you need to calculate the shadow-projection of the rotated disk onto the (x-z) plane, then determine if your candidate point lies within that shadow(which is an ellipse) or not.

Comment: I meant to say disk.  Given any (x,y,z) coordinates in 3D space, I need the distance along the y-axis from the given point to the disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, generate the ellipse that the rotated disk projects onto the x-z plane:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2388747/formula-for-ellipse-formed-from-projecting-a-tilted-circle-onto-the-xy-plane

It's a bit easier for this case because the disk is tilted 45 degrees. The major axis of the ellipse is just the diameter of the original disk, and the minor axis is related to the diameter by `diameter**2 = 2 * (minor**2)`.

Once you have the major and minor axis of this ellipse, it's not too hard to determine if the x,z components of the test point lie inside that ellipse, using this equation:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76457/check-if-a-point-is-within-an-ellipse

If the test point lies within the disk, then the y-component on the disk is as noted in above answer (for the 45 degree tilt only, but it is just a right triangle): `y = -z`
You've now found the point in x-y-z space that lies on the rotated disk, so just subtract that y-value from the test point's y-value to determine the distance to the disk along the y-axis.

Answer (score 1):

This is straightforward 3D analytic geometry.  First, note that there is no such thing as a "circular plane"; you have describe a circle and its interior, which, by definition, are embedding in a particular plane.

The equation of that plane is `y + z = 0`; `x` is an unconstrained variable, except as used to define the boundaries of the circle.

Thus, your problem reduces to simply

```
y = -z
```